# Fetch the manager from an email address

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to get the "Manager" of a specific person (and hopefully iterate for a targeted list after). How to do this for a specific email address and not the Global Address List?

```
Dim appOL As Outlook.Application ' Object
Dim oGAL As Outlook.AddressEntries ' .NameSpace  Object
Dim oContact As Outlook.AddressEntry ' Object
Dim oUser As ExchangeUser ' Object

Set appOL = New Outlook.Application ' CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oGAL = appOL.GetNameSpace("MAPI").AddressLists("Global Address List").AddressEntries("first.last@email.com")
oContact = oGAL.Item(1)
MsgBox oContact.Manager
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the lines

```
Set oGAL = appOL.GetNameSpace("MAPI").AddressLists("Global Address List").AddressEntries("first.last@email.com")
oContact = oGAL.Item(1)
```

with the following (assuming you are working with a selected message in Outlook):

```
if appOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count > 0 Then
  set msg = appOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
  set sender = msg.Sender
  if Not (sender is null) Then
    set manager = sender.Manager
  End If
End If
```

If you are working with an one-off name, use something like

```
set recip = appOL.Session.CreateRecipient("The name to resolve")
if recip.Resolve Then
  set manager = recip.AddressEntry.Manager
End If
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't specific on that. It's not a selected message. Looking to find manager for a specific user. Can I mimic this from a new draft email and the sender email in TO?

Comment: What is that specific user? Do you retrieve it by name?

Comment: I have name to retrieve by, but prefer using an email to retrieve the details.